# How am I supposed to use Java object reference?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple quiz for android,

I got told that I should try using an object reference.

I'm not quite sure how to do it, this is what I've done so far...

```
package com.aleksei.etb;
public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

       private String[] questions =
        {"Q1", 
         "Q2",
         "Q3", 
         "Q4",
         "Q5", //5
         "Q6", 
         "Q7", 
         "Q8", 
         "Q9",
         "Q10" //10
         };
         private String[] answers_correct =
        {"Correct answer - 1",
         "Correct answer - 2",
         "Correct answer - 3", 
         "Correct answer - 4",
         "Correct answer - 5",
         "Correct answer - 6",
         "Correct answer - 7",
         "Correct answer - 8",
         "Correct answer - 9",
         "Correct answer - 10"
         };

         private String[][] answers_wrong = 
         { {"Q1-1", "Q1-2" , "Q1-3"},
           {"Q2-1", "Q2-2" , "Q2-3"},
           {"Q3-1", "Q3-2" , "Q3-3"},
           {"Q4-1", "Q4-2" , "Q4-3"},
           {"Q5-1", "Q5-2" , "Q5-3"},
           {"Q6-1", "Q6-2" , "Q6-3"},
           {"Q7-1", "Q7-2" , "Q7-3"},
           {"Q8-1", "Q8-2" , "Q8-3"},
           {"Q9-1", "Q9-2" , "Q9-3"},
           {"Q10-1", "Q10-2" , "Q10-3"}

         };
         private int counter = 0;
         public Button answer_1,
         answer_2,answer_3,
         answer_4,skip;

         public TextView question_tv,
         tip_tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getData();
        quizBegin();
    }

    public static int getResults(){
       return 5;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            break;
        }
    }

    private void getData(){
        //Everything
        skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answer_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        answer_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        answer_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        answer_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        question_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        tip_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answ1);

        //Buttons
        skip.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Text
        skip.setText("Begin!");
        answer_4.setText("");
        answer_3.setText("");
        answer_2.setText("");
        answer_1.setText("");
        tip_tv.setText(""); 
    }

    private void quizBegin(){
        String question = Question.(questions[counter], answers_correct[counter],
                answers_wrong[counter],counter); //error here.

        //What am I suppose to do??
            // How to use an object reference??
            // Help please!

        question_tv.setText("");



        counter++;
    }



}
```

Question class, which encapsulates a question and its correct and incorrect answer.

```
public class Question {

    private String question;
    private String correctAnswer;
    private List<String> incorrectAnswers;
    private int counter = 0;



    public Question(final String question, final String correctAnswer, 
            final String[] incorrectAnswers, int counter) {
    // TODO: empty strings/nulls checks
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.incorrectAnswers = Arrays.asList(incorrectAnswers);
    }

    public List<String> getPossibleAnswers() {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.addAll(incorrectAnswers);
        result.add(correctAnswer);
        Collections.shuffle(result);
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isCorrectAnswer(final String answer) {
        if (answer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

}
```

Comment: Clarify what you want to do and don't use this as a code-dump.

Comment: I figured it out, it looks something like Question q_class = new Question(questions[counter], answers_correct[counter],
    answers_wrong[counter],counter);
  
  String question = q_class.getQuestion();
  
  question_tv.setText(question);, yes?

Comment: If that was what you were confused about your question was very misleading, that's [`object instantiation`](http://searchcio-midmarket.techtarget.com/definition/instantiation) (more info added as an edit to my question).

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess as to your actual question, but why are you using arrays of Strings to represent questions, answers correct, and incorrect answers? Why not use an array of `Question` objects and let the `Question` object manage if it was answered correctly or incorrectly.

**EDIT**

The statement `new Question(questions[counter], answers_correct[counter], answers_wrong[counter],counter);` calls the constructor in the `Question` class that takes the type, order, and number of parameters given to create an `instance` of the object.

```
Question q = new Question();
```

Creates a new `Question` object instance and assigns the reference to the variable `q`, this variable can be used to access information from the isntance of the `Question` class that it refers to. This is a basic concept for Object Oriented Programming.

**Second EDIT**

This line will work for you:

String[] sl = (String[]) q_class.getPossibleAnswers().toArray(new String[0]);

But the cast (`(String[])`) to a String array is pointless. The method `toArray(T[])` uses [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and returns an array with the same type as that of the array you pass to it. So passing `new String[0]` to the method guarantees you will be getting a `String[]` back. So you are casting a `String[]` into a `String[]`.

Do you really want to do this in the first place though? Why can you not use the `List<String>` in place of an array?

If you are doing a lot of casting from type to type, you should ask yourself if it's possible for you to adjust your code to operate on a single type.

(A sidenote, you can use backticks (`) to denote inline code sections, which helps keep those code snippets you put in comments easier to pull out and read).

Comment: Ah, thank you. But can you tell me how can I convert a list to array? I completly forgot.

Comment: @John Because it appears that you are new, instead of just giving you the answer I will provide you with a link to the API for the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class. You may be interested in it's `toArray` method.

Comment: @John My fault, I didn't notice you were declaring the variable as a `List<String>`. It doesn't change what you are looking for, the both have `toArray` methods that will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Is this correct? String[] sl = (String[]) q_class.getPossibleAnswers().toArray(new String[0]);